# How to use "Quartz.NET" with "SimpleIOC" of MVVM Light Toolkit?

Tags: dependency-injection, mvvm-light, ioc-container, factory-pattern, quartz.net

How can I integrate the [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net) scheduling library with [SimpleIOC](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/e2774a68-2132-6ab6-61a4-2eb3e8ae811b.htm), the IoC Container included in Laurent Bugnion's MVVM Light Toolkit?

My current plan is to simply register the Quartz scheduler factory and then get its instance whenever needed and/or inject it into my other services as needed. Like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
```

And then:

```
public SomeService(ISchedulerFactory quartzSchedulerFactory)
{
   //Quartz SchedulerFactory is here!
}
```

Is using Quartz.NET in this manner OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one instance of `ISchedulerFactory`. And it [looks](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/WP8/html/1125a2c3-9ec1-6faf-764d-1acaf286e904.htm) like SimpleIOC will always use the same instance, once it's created, so your approach is OK.

However I don't see any reason, why your services will ever need `ISchedulerFacgtory`. It's the `IScheduler` you want to inject. Consider the following:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IScheduler>( 
    () => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler());

public SomeService(IScheduler scheduler)
```